# Hash of the transaction VS Transaction Hash or Transaction ID

Tags: transactions

I just want to be sure I understood well how each of them are generated. I'm a bit confused because of the similarity of the names and because I couldn't find in the yellow paper how the transaction ID is generated.

**Hash of the transaction**

```
Keccak-256(nonce,gasPrice,gasLimit,to,value,data,v)
//Being the arguments not RLP encoded
```

Used to calculate the signature along with the private key through ECDSA Sign

**Transaction Hash/Transaction ID**

```
Keccak-256(RLP(nonce,gasPrice,gasLimit,to,value,data,v,r,s))
//Being the arguments RLP encoded
```

Tracking transaction ID given by the local node once the transaction is broadcasted

---

Can someone confirm I'm right or tell me why I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction ID calculation is correct. For the signing, the arguments are still RLP encoded (the dummy "v" for EIP-155 is a bit special, see below).

Take [this live transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x14a298c1eea89f42285948b7d51eeac2876ca7406c9784b9b90dd3591d156d64) as an example. It has the following parameters.

```
nonce = 0 [RLP: 0x80]
gasPrice = 50000000000 wei (0x0BA43B7400) [RLP: 85 0BA43B7400]
gasLimit = 21000 (0x5208) [RLP: 82 5208]
to = 0x7917bc33eea648809c285607579c9919fb864f8f [RLP: 94 7917bc33eea648809c285607579c9919fb864f8f]
value = 1050000000000000 wei (0x03BAF82D03A000) [RLP: 87 03BAF82D03A000]
data = <empty> [RLP: 80]
v = 018080 (this is a place-holder value before signing, see EIP-155)
```

Then the input parameters for the hash is the RLP of the concatenation:

```
EB80850BA43B7400825208947917bc33eea648809c285607579c9919fb864f8f8703BAF82D03A00080018080
```

And the hash value for the signing is:

```
python3
>>> from Crypto.Hash import keccak
>>> keccak_hash=keccak.new(digest_bits=256)
>>> txn=bytearray.fromhex('EB80850BA43B7400825208947917bc33eea648809c285607579c9919fb864f8f8703BAF82D03A00080018080')
>>> keccak_hash.update(bytes(txn))
<Crypto.Hash.keccak.Keccak_Hash object at 0x10fb6e2e8>
>>> print(keccak_hash.hexdigest())
```

which gives the result

```
a4060d01d4add248db470b4121616cbe5b2015daf328809000ec9a1d0954d649
```

For the transaction ID, do Keccak hash on the final raw transaction bytes (RLP encoded as you mentioned, which are also readable from Etherscan) and it will give the same result as shown on Etherscan.