# ecrecover not giving back the adress of the sender

Tags: raw-transaction, pyethereum, ecrecover

I am trying to understand how eliptic curve work and when i try to get the sender of this transaction: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x14a298c1eea89f42285948b7d51eeac2876ca7406c9784b9b90dd3591d156d64 ( spoiler the sender address is: 0x8d900bfa2353548a4631be870f99939575551b60). I follow the answer from this old question: [Hash of the transaction VS Transaction Hash or Transaction ID](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47978/hash-of-the-transaction-vs-transaction-hash-or-transaction-id/47984). And the ecrecover function i use is pyethereum.utils.ecrecover_to_pub.

But when i try to recover back the address, i can't get the sender address.

The function i used is: 

`hash = HexBytes('0xa4060d01d4add248db470b4121616cbe5b2015daf328809000ec9a1d0954d649')
ecrecover_to_pub(hash, 27, 0x067940651530790861714b2e8fd8b080361d1ada048189000c07a66848afde46, 0x69b041db7c29dbcc6becf42017ca7ac086b12bd53ec8ee494596f790fb6a0a69).hex()[-40:]`

which the result address is 0xd124db72eff486dad933df8cc5ec97acb26144ae

i think i have set the v, r, s right because i got the v, r, s using `web3.eth.getTransaction('0x14a298c1eea89f42285948b7d51eeac2876ca7406c9784b9b90dd3591d156d64')`.

The v, r, s from the result function are: `37, 0x067940651530790861714b2e8fd8b080361d1ada048189000c07a66848afde46, 0x69b041db7c29dbcc6becf42017ca7ac086b12bd53ec8ee494596f790fb6a0a69`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't you send 37 instead of 27 to ecrecover_to_pub as the value of v?

EDIT: Updating the answer, because in the comments the code is unreadable

simple contract in Solidity returns the correct address:

```
contract ECRecover {
    function ECR(bytes32 _Msg, uint8 _v, bytes32 _r, bytes32 _s) public pure returns (address) {
        return ecrecover(_Msg, _v, _r, _s);
    }
}
```

So the problem is with the python code ... from the docs:

> ecrecover_to_pub(hash, v, r, s) - recovers the public key that made
>   the signature as a 64-byte binary blob of encode_int32(x) +
>   encode_int32(y). Hashing this and taking the last 20 bytes gives the
>   address that signed a message.

It seems you are not hashing the result before taking the last 20 bytes, so it should be:

```
sha3(ecrecover_to_pub(hash, 27, 0x067940651530790861714b2e8fd8b080361d1ada048189000c07a66848afde46, 0x69b041db7c29dbcc6becf42017ca7ac086b12bd53ec8ee494596f790fb6a0a69).hex())[-40:]
```

Comment: According to the ethereum yellow paper, the fomula (291) and (292) say that the ecrecovet should be 27 if the v is odd and 28 if the v is even. So if u set the v different from that it will return address(0)