# Compute transaction hash locally?

Tags: transactions

The usual workflow to submit an EVM transaction seems to be:

1. Call the `send(Raw)Transaction` RPC method.
2. Use the returned transaction hash to query the status of your transaction.

My question is, is it possible to precompute the transaction hash before submitting the transaction to the node? I believe this would simplify the transaction tracking as it would allow me to start listening for the transaction right from the start. If instead I have to wait for the hash first, then once I receive the hash I first need to check the history whether the transaction has been mined already, and only then can I start looking for the transaction in new blocks.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Check the web3 framework for ways to do it. For example web3.js provides a "transactionHash" event when the hash becomes available.

Comment: I did that but can't find anything useful. I would expect that there should be a function `transactionHash(tx)` which takes a transaction object and computes its hash, but neither web3.js nor ethers.js seem to have such a function.

Answer (score 1):

For web3 there's [`web3.eth.signTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth.html#signtransaction) returns the hash of the transaction in the 'hash' field.

> ```
> {
>     raw: '0xf86c...',
>     tx: {
>         nonce: '0x0',
>         ...
>         hash: '0xda3be87732110de6c1354c83770aae630ede9ac308d9f7b399ecfba23d923384'
>     }
> }
> ```

Similarly [`web3.eth.sendTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) returns a [`PromiEvent`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth.html#eth-sendtransaction-return). This object provide several events that you can listen to, one of them is `transactionHash`

> ```
> // using the event emitter 
> web3.eth.sendTransaction({
>     from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
>     to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
>     value: '1000000000000000' })
> })
> .on('transactionHash', function(hash) {
>     // hash is available
> })
> .on('receipt', function(receipt){
>     // tx was mined
> })
> ```

Comment: `signTransaction` seems to only return the raw transaction for me :-(

Comment: @gTcV Which library are you using? My answer is for latest web3.js v1.7.x, for other languages there should be a similar library. If I remember correctly `hash = keccak256(rawTransaction)`. See here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47978/hash-of-the-transaction-vs-transaction-hash-or-transaction-id/47984#47984.